# Redirect method call and pass caller along automatically

Tags: python

I'm building a modular app and I wanted all Objects of a certain type to be able to call a management object, and automatically have their own instance passed along.

Scenario:
My application consists of a framework and plugins that are being loaded at runtime.
One of these plugins provides functionality that operates in a separate contexts for each plugin. Simply put: It receives the instance of the caller plugin and only operates with data associated with this plugin.
In order to avoid confusion in the following description, lets refer to the callee as management object and to the caller as worker object.
There is going to be one management object and multiple plugins:
Plugin + : 1 Management Object

I would like the worker object to be able to access the management functionality, without the need to specify the instance of the worker instance explicitly in the parameter list.

Instead, I'd like the management methods to look, as if they belonged to the worker object - so that the passing of the caller argument is transparent and implicit.

One possibility would be, to register all new management methods with the worker class directly. However, I don't like this "namespace pollution". Instead, I'd like them to be accessible via an attribute so that the meaning is clear.

Keep in mind, that this behaviour is added at runtime, and I do not wish to modify the Plugin class itself. Also, multiple plugins may already have been instantiated at that time, but I need this to work for all current and future instances.

The idea I've come up with, is to combine the descriptor `__get__` and `__getattr__` methods in one object.

The `__get__` method will be used, to determine the instance of the caller.

The `__getattr__` method will be used, to dynamically wrap the method that is being supposed to be called from the management object.

The code I've come up with looks like this:

```
my_management_object = getItHere()    
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._caller = None
     def __getattr__(self, name):
        method = getattr(my_management_object, name)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return method(self._caller, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
     def __get__(self, caller, type):
        self._caller = caller
        return self
MyPluginClass._manage = Wrapper()
```

So now, I can do:

```
obj = MyPluginClass()
obj._manage.doSomethingForMe()
#vs:
getMyManagementObject().doSomethingForMe(obj)
```

I have tested it and it seems to work.
I was wondering whether there are any pitfalls in this method or whether there are more pythonic ways to do this. I'm pretty new to the Descriptor stuff so I may have overlooked something.

Comment: Why aren't you using ordinary decorators for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I'd like all objects that descend from a certain type to have this functionality and they shouldn't need to change anything by themselves. By "ordinary" decorators, I assume you mean the @ notation? Wouldn't that mean, that I do this in the definition of the class? But this funcionatliy is provided by an additional module which is being loaded at runtime. So basically, I'd like to have an attribute which acts as a generic decorator calling the method with the same name of a certain object as this name of this attribute's attribute.

Comment: Maybe a more simple answer for your question would be the following: Because I don't know how to achieve this effect otherwise - hence the question.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why you aren't using simple inheritance from a "management" class.  Except for very specific, well thought out, and well implemented cases, I find decorators and descriptor techniques to be more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: As I already mentioned in my first post, it's a modular application and this module just adds a nice shortcut for other modules to access that module's functionality. (module = plugin, not in the python sense) - In the end, it doesn't really matter what it does and whether the code structure is reasonable this way, because I cannot explain the entire setup. But I would just like this sort of accessing methods from another object.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is accessing attributes, use a descriptor.  It appears that you're implementing a descriptor-like design and calling it a "Wrapper".  A descriptor will probably be slightly simpler and more consistent with all the other places in Python that use descriptors.

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors

Making this a more typical descriptor class may save you some work.

Comment: The only reason I use a descriptor, is to get the instance on which the class currently operates.
Again, I don't know what exactly you'd like me to do. I can see that the name "Wrapper" may be somewhat confusing at this point.
Could you perhaps post a code example on what you had in mind?

Comment: Or do you mean, implement all the attributes of the class that are being accessed through my dubious way as descriptors, so that I can get the caller from the __get__ method directly?

Comment: on second thought, that wouldn't work, since I'd get the instance of the callee. So I'm back to zero: I don't know what you mean. Or I never knew what I thought you meant. lol

Comment: "that wouldn't work, since I'd get the instance of the callee".  How is that a problem?

Comment: My goal is, to pass the caller along automatically.
Let's assume the scenario, where we have a worker object and a management object: I want to be able, to call a method from the management object and pass the instance of the worker object along, without having to explicitely specify it.
If I implement the methods on the management object via the descriptor protocol, I'm going to get the management object itself each time - but that is no use to me, because it will only exist once.

Comment: On the other hand, I could implement descriptors for all methods that the management object possesses on the worker object. But that would require me, to add and remove descriptors each time I add or remove a method on the management object.

That's why I have made one descriptor and combined it with the __ getattr __ method to dynamically access a method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still haven't figured out, what you mean by "making this a more typical descriptor class".

Comment: @phant0m: "Let's assume the scenario..." That's your real question isn't it?  Please **update** your question to include this information.  Please explain why you're not using the standard `descriptor` protocol for this.  Please provide some details **in the question** not in the comments.

Comment: @phant0m: 'I still haven't figured out what you mean by "making this a more typical descriptor class"'.  Does that mean you did not read the definition of a descriptor class?  What does that mean?  The definition is perfectly clear.  Do I need to repeat it in my answer?

Comment: Hmm... I have read the defintion and I realize that what I'm doing is not really the purpose for descriptors.
As for the scenario: As I stated in the original question, the goal is to pass the caller along automatically. The scenario I mentioned in the comment isn't really the real thing either. I'm sorry for being so unspecific. I'll go over my original question again and try to fill in any information that might be important.